# Mongoose schema is not Storing all thing in database

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am trying to create a simple registration form using the MEAN stack using mongoose. Here is my **models/dbSchema.js**

```html
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var User = new mongoose.Schema({
   FirstName: String,
   LastName:  String,
   City    :  String,
   Email   :  String,
   Userid  :  String,
   Password:  String
    
});
module.export = mongoose.model('user', User);
```

and this is my **server.js**

```html
var express = require('express');
var app =  express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');



app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));


// configure app to use bodyParser()
// this will let us get the data from a POST
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Regis_module');
var Userschema = require('./models/dbSchema'); 

 app.post('/regi',function(req,res){
     var schema        =  new Userschema();
     schema.Firstname      =  req.body.Fname;
     schema.Lastname      =  req.body.Lname;
     schema.City       =  req.body.city;
     schema.Email      =  req.body.email;
     schema.Userid     =  req.body.userid;
     schema.Password   =  req.body.password;
     
  schema.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Record Inserted', Firstname: req.body.firstname, Lastname: req.body.lastname, city:req.body.city, email:req.body.email, 
                       userid:req.body.userid, password :req.body.password /*, fbId : req.body.fbId*/ });
        });
        
    });
    
app.listen(3000);
console.log("listening to port 3000");
```

On localhost, at the time of form submission, Firstname and Lastname does not store in the database. City, email, userid and password are stored  correctly.

How can I store all thing in database correctly please help me ?

Comment: Make sure are u getting firstname, lastname from req.body correctly?

Comment: can you post the HTML form, I assume something there is not ok

Comment: the issue might be that you are not getting the values of `Fname` and `Lname` in request. try logging the req.body and see what it prints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following lines of code you use `req.body.Fname` and `req.body.Lname` :

```
schema.Firstname = req.body.Fname;
schema.Lastname = req.body.Lname;
```

and in the next lines you use `req.body.firstname` and `req.body.lastname`:

```
 res.json({ message: 'Record Inserted', Firstname: req.body.firstname, Lastname: req.body.lastname, city:req.body.city, email:req.body.email, 
                   userid:req.body.userid, password :req.body.password /*, fbId : req.body.fbId*/ });
    });
```

If your `req.body` object has the same keys as your `User` Schema you could use mongoose's [`Model.create`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) method and just pass it `req.body`.

For your code you would do the following:

1. Bring the User model into your `server.js` file (`let User = require('./models/dbSchema.js')`)
2. Then your `app.post` would look like the following:

   ```
   app.post('/regi', function(req,res) {
    //pass the .create method the data from the body
     User.create(req.body, (err, savedUser) => {
       if(err) return res.send(err);
       res.send(savedUser);
     });
   });
   ```